# ViewController with scroll when appear keyboard

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

i want see all my view but when appear the keyboard i dont see all, for example:

```
-------------------------------------------
- --------------------------------------- -    i want what my viewcontroller have scroll
- -        text field 1                 - -
- -        text field 2                 - -
- -        text field n                 - -
- ------------------------------------- - -
-------------------------------------------
-                                         -
-               keyboard                  -
-                                         - 
- -                                     - -
- ------------------------------------- - -
```

This is my code, by mean with this code i can fix in the one of my textfield, i am using this IsFirstResponder for what i can see the current textfield, but i want see all of the my textfields, can i put a scroll?:

is posible put a scroll? i checked many applications and i think what is possible.

```
public static void KeyBoardUpNotification(NSNotification notification)
        {
            scrollamount = 0.0f;

            RectangleF rectangle = (RectangleF)UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification(notification);


            bottom = ((float)(activeview.Frame.Y + activeview.Frame.Height + offset));
            scrollamount = ((float)(rectangle.Height - (currentView.Frame.Size.Height - bottom)));

            if (scrollamount != 0)
            {
                moveViewUp = true;
                ScrollTheView(moveViewUp);
            }
            else
            {
                moveViewUp = false;
            }
        }

        public static void KeyBoardDownNotification(NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (moveViewUp) ScrollTheView(false);
        }

        private static void ScrollTheView(bool move)
        {
            UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3);
            RectangleF frame = (RectangleF)currentView.Frame;

            if (move)
            {
                frame.Y = y;
                frame.Y -= scrollamount;    
            }
            else
            {
                frame.Y = y;
                scrollamount = 0;
                moveViewUp = false;
            }
            currentView.Frame = frame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();
            scrollamount = 0;
            frame.Y = 0;
```

Comment: why not using UITableViewController?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry why is a screen without table, is not requerid a tableView

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin **Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager** from nuget.

**Usage**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.EnableAutoToolbar = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldToolbarUsesTextFieldTintColor = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.KeyboardDistanceFromTextField = 300f;
    //...
}
```

For more details you could check https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager